# How to convert pygame application to iOS app

Tags: python, ios, python-3.x, iphone, pygame

I wrote a very small and unfinished game in python using pygame. Is there an easy way to convert this to an app which I can use and test on my iPhone without rewriting the whole code in things like kivvy?

Answer (score -3):

There isn't an easy way, it's impossible transform the code.
But for an easy and not professional game, you can try to do this.

Use a site for hosting the game like Python Anywhere (free).
Now create an app without any coding skill.
I never use IOS, for android MIT Inventor is a good framework for create apps.
For Ios, you can try Appypie or Appyourself, but you can find other better alternatives.

The app must contain a web-browser viewer with your site.
The app shows a web page with your game in it.

I can't imagine another way, it's a bit difficult and the app require internet connection.
Good luck!

Comment: That's not really converting to an app, it's just running the app on some other machine and viewing it through a web view. Might as well not bother with the app and just use a web browser.

Comment: Apple’ll reject this app for sure